# Solve HTML Canvas image-rendering DOWNGRADE issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, canvas

These days, while trying to render some graphics in a HTML page with canvas, I fot the following issue: The canvas element is downgrading my images while rendering, after some time.

Here's the issue visualized:

> [image]
> Image to render (32x32)

> [image]
>
> Rendering at first instance (with browser zoom)

> [image]
>
> How the image gets after some moves (by keyboard events), randomly

> Note 1: I'm not resizing the image!

> Note 2: The function responsible to draw is being called every 10 miliseconds

> Note 3: I'm using `image-rendering: pixelated` for canvas in CSS

> Note 4: Here's the function responsible for drawing it:

```
    function draw_player(x,y,w,h,state){
    
        if(state>2){ctx.drawImage(player_sprite_jump, x,y, w,h)}
        if(state<=1){ctx.drawImage(player_sprite_left, x,y, w,h)}
        if(state===2){ctx.drawImage(player_sprite_right, x,y, w,h)}
}
```

(w and h are, again, 32, I'm not resizing the image anywhere!)

> Note 5: I'm using HTML, CSS and only vanilla JS

If any other info is needed, I would like to contribute.

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: You must create a complete snippet

Comment: You must render at pixel boundaries. If you are not using `transform`, `scale`, `rotate`, `translate`, or `setTransform` you can align to pixel boundaries with `ctx.drawImage(img, Math.round(x), Math.round(y), w, h);` (Making x and y integer values) You can also render using nearest pixel by setting `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false`  however that will still need alignment to pixels to avoid artifacts.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it was happening by `imageSmoothingEnabled`, that is set 'true' by default

It tries to smooth the image, and removes pixels's sharpness!

**Resolution:** `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;`